# How to downgrade from windows 10 to windows 8.1 by windows 8.1 disc?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10, downgrade

I upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10 and I want back to windows 8.1, but I can't use recovery method because I deleted windows.old folder from my drive. 
I have original windows 8.1 (setup files) and serial number, 
 How to use it to downgrade without losing my apps and files??

Comment: "How to use it to downgrade without losing my apps and files??" - You can't, you have removed the ONLY method of doing so.  Download the Windows 8.1 Media Creation Tool and install Windows 8.1. This will mean you have to format your HDD to reinstall Windows 8.1 of course.

Comment: @Ramhound ..In disk drive I have two partitions C (for windows) and E .. If I used clean installation, Will the E disk partition be deleted??

Comment: The installer only modifies the partition you select.  How the installer works has not changed in over a decade.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Windows 10 allows you to go back to previous version of windows within 30 days of Installation. In your case you have already deleted the windows.old you are left with two options either you keep using windows 10 or install Operating System again. If you go for clean installation of windows again you can not save your apps however you can take backup of your data saved on any external drive or cloud.

Comment: In disk drive I have two partitions C (for windows) and E .. If I used clean installation, Will the E disk partition be deleted??

Comment: It depends on your choice. While you try to install any version of windows there comes a screen where you need to select the partition where you want the Operating System(Windows) to be installed. On that screen Select "C" drive and format it and then select next. Leave partition  "E" as it is do not modify that.

Comment: If that helped please select it as answer.

Comment: done!!!!!! :-) ^_^

Answer (score -2):

How long ago was this? As you are unable to rollback after [30 Days](https://techingiteasy.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/how-to-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-windows-from-windows-10/) - However, If the reason you do not have the windows.old is because of the 30 days i am unsure if you able to roll back especially without a backup.

You could possibly backup your files to an external device and then reinstall 8.1

Comment: If you are not sure of what they can or cannot do.  What exactly are you submitting as their answer to their question?

Comment: In disk drive I have two partitions C (for windows) and E .. If I used clean installation, Will the E disk partition be deleted??

Comment: Because i need 50 reputation to comment on main posts?